# Is it possible to have systemd open a program running in a clean terminal automatically after startup?

Tags: systemd, raspbian, executable

First off apologies for the simple question- there is more to it that I will explain below.

I am new to Linux style systems and evidently I have *A LOT* to learn.

With that said...

**My System**

I am running a program on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. My operating system is Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

**What I Have**

I have produced a working program in C++ that is stored in `home/pi/Dev`. The program has no GUI but prints information into the terminal.
The program infinitely loops (using an empty `for` loop).

When launching the program through Geany (an editor on the pi), I can make and run the program which opens a new terminal window and prints the output there.

When clicking on the executable file in the folder I'm asked to choose between 'Execute' and 'Execute in terminal'.

- Selecting to 'Execute' seemingly has no effect (I have looked for the process in the task manager?)
- Selecting to 'Execute in Terminal' brings up an error: `Failed to execute child process “xterm” (No such file or directory)`

When using the terminal and running `./myprogram` The program runs, printing the output in the already open terminal window.

**What I Want**

I would like the program to run automatically on startup.

The Pi will be used 'headless' but with the graphical interface enabled so I can see the desktop using VNC; when I open the VNC connection I would like a terminal to be running and displaying the program output.

**What I Have Tried**

I have been attempting to use systemd to launch the program.

At first I tried launching the program directly but got absolutely nowhere; I couldn't find any good info or examples online and most examples were using bash or Python scripts... If you can't beat them join them...

So next I created (copied) a simple bash script in usr/local/bin/ called `procamStartup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo test
cd /home/pi/Dev/
./Procam
```

and when running this script using `./procamStartup.sh`, "test" was printed in the terminal and then the program started printing below that.. so the script  in my eyes is functional.

Next I created a `service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/` called `procamStartup.service`:

```
[Unit]
 Description=Procam Startup Script
 After=graphical.target

 [Service]
 Type=idle
 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/procamStartup.sh

 [Install]
 WantedBy=graphical.target
```

I chose `Type = idle` so the system would wait for all processes to finish before launching.

I chose `WantedBy=graphical.target` so the program would only launch after the graphical interface has started.

I set execute permissions for both script and service folders using:

- `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/procamStartup.sh`
- `sudo chmod +x /etc/systemd/system/procamStartup.service`

I next told systemd to reload the files:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

and then enabled the script to be ran at boot:

`sudo systemctl enable procamStartup.service`

after that I ran `sudo reboot`.

**Continued**

So.. before sending this post I followed my own instruction and at the end ran:

`sudo systemctl status procamStartup.service`

Which reported the service was successfully running and printing the program output into a log.

This is semi-ok: I can use the Pi as intended as the program is running- just with no output showing by default.

So to redo my question:

***Is it possible to have systemd open a program running in a clean terminal automatically after startup?***

I also think I need to change the service file; since its running a script that runs the program I might be launching several instances of the same program?

Thank you for reading.

**Continued continued**

I have now installed `xterm`

I have changed my script to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -hold -e /home/pi/Dev/Procam
```

When running this script through the Pi GUI terminal, I get exactly what I want: a new window outputting correctly.

When running this from startup or through SSH I get the following errors:

`xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s`

`xterm: DISPLAY is not set`

I'm currently looking into resolving this.

Comment: Does it need to be systemd? You normally do this sort of thing at the user-level: you just have the tool run after login. Is systemd an absolute requirement for you?

Comment: @terdon No it's not at all a requirement. 

when searching for methods online for having programs run from boot, systemd was described as a new method that is being widely adopted. 

I also appreciated the learning experience/ getting my head deeper into the architecture.

That being said I'm happy with any method that will allow a user to plug the Pi in, log onto the VNC and see the terminal widow printing away..

Comment: Does the program require to write to  or interact through a terminal? Can't the usual log file be enough?

Comment: Hello @A.B
Yes it is preferable to be writing to the terminal- The users will not be technically minded and I would prefer them to be able to just VNC on without control and see the current status that will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get the functionality I was after.

I edited my script in `/usr/local/bin/` (`procamStartup.sh`) to now read the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 xterm -hold -e /home/pi/Dev/Procam
```

and have edited my service file in `/etc/systemd/system/` (`procamStartup.service`) to:

```
[Unit]
 Description=Procam Startup Script
 After=graphical.target

 [Service]
 Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
 DISPLAY=:0
 User=pi
 Type=idle
 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/procamStartup.sh
 User=pi
 Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority

 [Install]
 WantedBy=graphical.target
```

After reloading with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and a `sudo reboot` I now connect to VNC to see the program in its own terminal window already running away.

Great news on a Friday :)

Have a good weekend everyone!