# systemd to open a commandline and execute a program in it on bootup

Tags: systemd, terminal, rhel

I have made a `custom_start.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` {OS is redhat linux 8.2}

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto Start

[Service]
User=ABC
WorkingDirectory=/home/ABC/Desktop/
ExecStart=bash -c "./EFG"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The commands `systemctl daemon-reload`
and `systemctl start custom_start.service` is making the program `EFG` to run in background.
The status is shown as active upon executing `systemctl status custom_start.service`.

I want to run the program `EFG` on a new terminal (gnome-terminal/xterm) and be able to see the commandline outputs on the terminal.

I have seen a similar post for raspbian os : [Is it possible to have systemd open a program running in a clean terminal automatically after startup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617201/is-it-possible-to-have-systemd-open-a-program-running-in-a-clean-terminal-automa)

Comment: Maybe just add `xterm`? Like:  `ExecStart=bash -c "xterm ./full/path/EFG"`

Comment: Maybe just add `xterm`? Like:  `ExecStart=bash -c "xterm ./full/path/EFG"`